# Using 'virtual' in derived class

Tags: c++, virtual

I saw code in a derived class recently in which the programmer put `virtual` in front of the functions overridden. Is this common? I thought it was very odd and it kind of caught me off guard.

Edit: I'm not asking what virtual does, I'm asking why someone would put virtual in a derived class that is already overriding virtual functions in its base class.

EX:

```
class B {
 public:
  virtual void foo();
  ....
};

class D : public B {
 public:
  virtual void foo(); // could have just put void foo();
  ...
};
```

Comment: I always do this, too, just to document my code.

Comment: This is something where I think C# is better, by forcing derived classes to use the `override` keyword.

Comment: This is perfect question , which answered many of my queries about how virtual works. Thanks @Person

Comment: **These answers are outdated: as of C++11, there is an [`override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).** In futue code, please use this keyword to mark functions that override a virtual function in the base class.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`virtual` is needed for overrideable functions at the highest (least derived) level.  It is optional, but harmless at lower (more derived) levels.  It's good for self-documenting the code.

Comment: Exactly. The compiler already knows, but other people reading your code might have to track back through multiple header files to find out.

Answer (score 12):

**These answers (and this practice) are outdated.** As of C++11, you should use the [`override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to explicitly specify that a virtual function overrides another virtual function. Your compiler will throw an error if you try to `override` something that isn't a virtual function in the base class!

Answer (score 10):

It is very common. Many style guides recommend it, e.g. [Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Inheritance#Inheritance).
The purpose is to enhance readability of the code.

Comment: New link here http://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Inheritance  The link says to use `override` or `virtual` *but not both*.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything odd in it. In many cases (if not most of the time) programmers create the declaration of the overriding function in the derived class by copy-pasting it from the base class. There's no point in spending the additional effort to manually remove the redundant `virtual` specifier. Moreover, the explicit `virtual` makes it easier to see which functions are virtual.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to enhance readability is to use something like this:

```
class B {
 public:
  virtual void foo();
  ....
};

class D : public B {
 public:
  /*override*/ void foo();
  ...
};
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write a comment when you have a reserved word exactly for the same purpose. The best way to document to your code is through the code itself. I recommend reading "The Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin, "Uncle" Bob.

Comment: The answer was published back in the day when the 'override' keyword was not available in the language;)

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you know the purpose of the virtual keyword but wondering why it suddenly appears in a subtype. If I am mistaken, my answer probably won't make much sense but any C++ reference will do.

It is perfectly legal to put virtual in a derived class. As a result, if you have a reference or pointer to that class or any of its subclasses, invocations of this function would be bound dynamically based on the runtime type.

While legal, however, it is not considered good design to have a nonvirtual method in the base class and virtual in an overridden version.

One reason is that you could have an instance of the derived class, and then one pointer to base and one pointer to the derived, and have both pointers aiming at this instance. Invoking the same function on each pointer would then have a different result, since invoking on the pointer declared with the base class would target the definition in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

This will help if future derivations also. If someone wants to derive class D and have virtual functions, then its easy to understand